# Mysql: How to Retrieve data for the current date and subtract 7 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

Would like to be able to run a report that counts all the new contacts created daily and adjusts -7 hours to the appropriate timezone since we log everything in UTC. Tried the below statement but doesn;t appear to be rendering the desired results.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table.x where date(created_date) = curdate() and date_add(hh,-7,created_date);
```

Comment: Your code is not consistent with MySQL.  Which is incorrect -- the code or the tag?  Is `curdate()` UTC or not?

Answer (score 0):

You want the date *after* subtracting out the offset.  I think that is:

```
where date(created_date + interval 7 hour) = curdate()
```

However, you would want an index-safe version, which I think is:

```
where created_date >= date(curdate() - interval 7 hour) + interval 7 hour and
      created_date < date(curdate() - interval 7 hour) + interval (7 + 24) hour
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! The first statement did the trick, but was gettng syntax errors with the second. Not sure I fully understand the concept of "index-safe" though...